# Count number of specific data in database and show 0 if there is blank or null. PHP

Tags: php

I am trying to get a count for how many students are in a particular level. In the dropdown select you should see the number of students at that level.

In the database there are currently 3 students. 2 are novice and 1 is open champion. When I did my code the first time and echo the count it will correctly show up as Novice (2) and Open Champion (1). However the rest are showing up blank like this: Beginner ().

I adjusted my code to include an `if statement` so that it will show up as (0) if there are no students at that level. The problem this time though is that everything comes up as (0) including Novice and Open Champion when it should be 2 and 1.

Can someone tell me what i'm doing wrong?

**CODE:**

```
<div class="col-sm-2 " style="text-align: right;">
              <select class="level">
                 <option value="all">All Levels</option>
                  <?php
                  $lvlnum = "SELECT * FROM `dancers` WHERE school = '$ownerSchool'";
                  $lvlres = mysqli_query($con,$lvlnum);



                  while($lvlrow = mysqli_fetch_array($lvlres)){
                      $placement[] = $lvlrow['current_lvl'];
                  }

                  $placeNum = array_count_values($placement);
                  $preBeginner = $placeNum["Pre Beginner"];
                  if($preBeginner = '' || $preBeginner = 'null'){
                      $preBeginner = 0;
                  }
                  $beginner = $placeNum["Beginner"];
                  if($beginner = '' || $beginner = 'null'){
                      $beginner = 0;
                  }
                  $novice = $placeNum["Novice"];
                  if($novice = '' || $novice = 'null'){
                      $novice = 0;
                  }
                  $prizeWinner = $placeNum["Prize Winner"];
                  if($prizeWinner = '' || $prizeWinner = 'null'){
                      $prizeWinner = 0;
                  }
                  $prelim = $placeNum["Prelim Champion"];
                  if($prelim = '' || $prelim = 'null'){
                      $prelim = 0;
                  }
                  $open = $placeNum["Open Champion"];
                  if($open = '' || $open = 'null'){
                      $open = 0;
                  }



                  ?>
                  <option value="Pre-Beginner"> Pre-Beginner (<?php echo $preBeginner ?>)</option>
                  <option value="Beginner"> Beginner (<?php echo $beginner ?>)</option>
                  <option value="Novice"> Novice (<?php echo $novice ?>)</option>
                  <option value="Prize Winner"> Prize Winner (<?php echo $prizeWinner ?>)</option>
                  <option value="Prelim Champion"> Prelim Champion (<?php echo $prelim ?>)</option>
                  <option value="Open Champion"> Open Champion (<?php echo $open ?>)</option>
              </select>
          </div>
```

Comment: `$prizeWinner = '' || $prizeWinner = 'null'`, use equality or identity. right now its assignment operator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Empty string and null string is not the same than null value.
A ternary operator (aka inline IF) may be helpful:

```
$preBeginner = isset($placeNum["Pre Beginner"]) ? $placeNum["Pre Beginner"] : 0;
```

Comment: Worked perfectly!! Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use this:

```html
<div class="col-sm-2 " style="text-align: right;">
    <select class="level">
       <option value="all">All Levels</option>
        <?php
          $lvlnum = "SELECT current_lvl as Placement, Count(Your Primary Key) as DancersOnPlacement FROM `dancers` WHERE school = '$ownerSchool'";
          $lvlres = mysqli_query($con,$lvlnum);

          while($lvlrow = mysqli_fetch_array($lvlres))
          {
            $Placement = $lvlrow['Placement'];
            $Count = $lvlrow['DancersOnPlacement'];

            echo "<option value='".$Placement."'>".$Placement." (".$Count.")</option>";

          }
        ?>
    </select>
</div>
```